# Dart simplify method call for null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this logic:

```
title: Text(widget.text != null ? transform(widget.text!) : 'default'),
```

I'm using ternary operator to call the *transform* function (it doesn't accept null parameters) only if text is not null.

Is there a way using some null safe operators to simplify this?

**Edit:**

Let's say transform function returns text + " 12", like this:

```
String transform(String a) {
    return a + " 12";
  }
```

And let's suppose I can not change that function

Comment: What does the `transform` function do?

Comment: if your `text` field accepts null values this is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you could modify your `transform` function to return a default value in case the provided one is null (see below).

```dart
String transform(String? a) {
    if (a == null) return 'default';
    return a + " 12";
}


// Then you should just be able to do this.
title: Text(transform(widget.text)),
```

**OLD ANSWER**

One way to simplify this would be something like this:

```dart
title: Text(transform(widget.text ?? 'default')),
```

The above code assumes that the `transform` function doesn't return a nullable value. If `transform` does return a nullable value, then you have to do this.

```dart
title: Text(transform(widget.text ?? 'default') ?? 'default'),
```

**What does the `??` do you ask?**

The `??` checks if the value before it is null, and if it is then it returns the value to the right of it. If the value to the left of it is **not** null, then it'll return that value instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it won't work for my case because the text field will get the value returned by transform function sending 'default' as parameter, so if it changes the text I will get something different from 'default'. (see my edit)

Comment: It's a nice solution but I just put a simplified example here, I can not change the function in the real case

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce the following helper method (yes, the naming could be better so please improve in your own project):

```
O callIfNotNull<I extends Object, O>(I? input, O Function(I) function,
        {required O ifNull}) =>
    input != null ? function(input) : ifNull;
```

This would allow us to do this:

```
title: callIfNotNull(widget.text, transform, ifNull: 'default')
```