# Syntactic sugar for calling a function with a nullable value that might return null

Tags: flutter, dart, operators, dart-null-safety, syntactic-sugar

I am looking for syntactic sugar with null-safe-operators to do this:

```dart
map["key"] == null ? default : (int.tryParse(map["key"]!) ?? default)
```

This however accesses `map` twice and requires `default` twice.
Better, but verbose code that also compiles:

```dart
String? val = map["key"];
int? res;
if (val != null) { res = int.tryParse(val) }
res ??= default;
```

In essence I am looking for a way to only call a function if the parameter is not null. E.g. in kotlin you could do (pseudocode)

```kotlin
map["key"].let{ int.tryParse(it) } ...
```

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755057/dart-simplify-method-call-for-null-value), however writing helper methods is even more verbose and I cannot edit the function to take nullable parameters.

What i would love to see for dart (but afaik this does not exist):

```dart
int.tryParse(map["key"]?) ?? default;
```

I.e. `func(null?) => null`, no matter what `func` is, or sth similar.

Is there a smooth way to do that or is the verbose way for now the "accepted" way?

**EDIT**
I am aware of the `int.tryParse("")` or `int.tryparse(default.toString()` hacks, however both are somewhat naughty as they will call tryParse either way instead of skipping it if the value is null anyways. (imagine replacing tryParse with a very expensive factory method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two things you can do:

```
int.parse(map["key"] ?? default.toString());
```

This would work if you are sure that map["key"] can be parsed if it is not null.
If you have to do this operation a lot you can also write your own extension function and then use the null-safe operator:

```
extension NullSaveParser on String {
    int? tryToInt() {
        return int.tryParse(this);
    }
}
```

And then use this:

```
map["key"]?.tryToInt() ?? default;
```

This extension is neccessary because there is currently no way in dart to not call a method if an argument would be null, only if the object that you are calling it on is null can be caught.
I hope this helps.

Comment: So it is not possible (with only dart operators), thank you!
I will accept your answer since the extension method is the cleanest way I can imagine for now

Answer (score 1):

It's sort of a hack and maybe ugly but for this case you might want to write something like

```
int.tryParse(map["key"] ?? '') ?? default
```

That is, put a fallback value inside the `tryParse` that you know will make the `tryParse` return `null`

Comment: Thank you! While "cleanest" this will always force `tryParse` to be called. I edited my question